# read unknown number of lines in f#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, c#-to-f#

Say I have `n` (7 in this case) inputs given

> 10
>
> 20
>
> 30
>
> 40
>
> 50
>
> 60
>
> 70

How do I read all inputs and store them in a list/array?

I tried this,

```
let inputList = [
    while (let line = Console.ReadLine()) <> null do
        line |> int
]
```

The idea was to read until I get an empty line.

But I get the following error,

> Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.

Comment: This looks to me like you have tried to translate some C# to F#.  You probably need an F# tutorial.  This one here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Control_Flow has about 90% of what you need

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do this in a functional style, you can use `Seq.initInfinite` to create a sequence from the console. 
Then you need to terminate this list when you get a null value using `Seq.takeWhile`. Beyond that, you can use all `Seq` module functions available including `Seq.toList`.

```
let read _ = Console.ReadLine()
let isValid = function null -> false | _ -> true
let inputList = Seq.initInfinite read |> Seq.takeWhile isValid |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, comparing against null will not work. Also you will need to add a Seq.map to convert to integers.

Comment: @Gustavo `Console.ReadLine()` returns `null` if `CTRL+Z` is pressed. I can only assume that's what the OP is intending; otherwise, one can add an empty string clause to the match expression.

Comment: Yes, that's a small detail, I think a better option is to use `System.String.IsNullOrEmpty`this way you cover both cases.